# Query string and AJAX navigation

Tags: php, jquery, navigation, query-string, jquery-address

I'm using JQuery Address for a fairly simple ajax navigation, with an index.php which loads pages into a container . This is the jquery:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {  
    // Get URL:
    var url = event.value.replace('/','');  
    if (url != '') { 
        $('#internalcontent').load(url); 
    }
});  

$('a').livequery('click',function() {  
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));  
    return false;
});
```

This works for most links (e.g. test.php) and for some query strings (e.g. test.php?id=3). But it doesn't work for a URL with a query string like test.php?d=4&c=2. Instead it just loads this page into a blank window, not into the container div. I'm pretty new to Address and I'm sure this is quite simple, but I can't figure out why there's an inconsistency between the two examples, i.e. why it works for test.php?id=3 but not for test.php?d=4&c=2.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your new test.php has a response for the appearance of both $_GET['d'] and $_GET['c']?

Comment: Yes. The test.php loads and displays the correct information, but it doesn't load in the <div> in the index.php, it just appears instead of index.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a' ,function() {  
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));  
    return false;
});
```